# Excel warning system idea

Tags: vba, excel, warnings

I am trying to create a warning system in Excel but I have no idea which function could be of aid.

say for example, I want a system that alerts me when the cell number is more than 5. and the signal stays on **even after** it went below 5.

cell A1 is RTD and it is a number that changes frequently.

> At 9AM, the number is 5.
>
> At 10AM, it changes to 10.
>
> At 11AM, it is back to 5.

How can I have a warning system that stays on, even at 11am, to notify me that this number has been more than 5. the "Warning" will remain on until I turn it off.

And even ideally, can Excel do a pop up or some sort to alert me on this warning.

thanks and regards

gyx

Comment: Yes it can, you would want vba in a Worksheet_Change or Worksheet_Calulate event.

Comment: This is beyond the capabilities of Excel cell formulas. You'll need to write a VBA script.

Answer (score 1):

Try Data Validation Lists.

For instance, if your Purchase Date is in Cell A1 and your return date is in cell B1 then do the following for cell B1:

(Steps Assume you use Excel 2007)

1. Select Cell B1
2. Go to the Data toolbar
3. Select Data Validation
4. For "Settings" tab, select "Custom"
5. In the formula Bar, type the formula "=B1>A1"
6. On the "Error Alert" tab, select Warning (Allows entry but shows a message box when condition isn't met)
7. For Title, type "Error"
8. For Error Message, type "Return Date cannot be before Purchase Date"

Should do exactly what you want...no code!!!! Same type of logic can be applied to do your advanced messaging, just need to update the formula in step 5 with some AND or maybe OR functions and you'll be on your way.

Comment: hi. this is genius. fantastic that i don't have to use VBA

Comment: however, when im testing this, it doesnt really work when cell A1 and B1 are formulas. for example, both cell uses sum formula. any idea how so?

Answer (score 0):

At first, set a name for the specified cell number which you want to system alerts when it's value is more than 5:

1. Click on the cell to be selected.
2. In the `Name Box` (At Up-Left side of the Excel window, Left side of the formula bar) Type a desired name, for example `Alert`

---

In your Workbook window Press <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd>

Microsoft Visual Basic For Application window will opens.

At left-up side, in the project explorer box, choose your specified worksheet. (For example: Sheet1)

Enter code below (Here also warns you with the status bar)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If ActiveSheet.Name = Me.Name Then
        If IsNumeric(Range("Alert").Value) Then
            If Range("Alert").Value > 5 Then
                MsgBox "The value is larger than 5", vbCritical + vbOKOnly, "Alert"
                Application.StatusBar = "Warning: the sensitive cells value is larger than 5"
            Else
                Application.StatusBar = "The sensitive cell is approved"
            End If
        Else
            Application.StatusBar = ""
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```